# Приложение для iPhone для управления os X

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

Возможно ли написать приложение, чтобы через него можно было управлять mac'ом? например изменить уровень яркости, но при этом не предустанавливая никаких программ на сам mac

Comment: нет, нельзя....

Comment: @markov обоснуйте

Comment: Вероятно я всё же туплю, думал, что AirPlay что-то подобное умеет, но почитал - нет